# Did I ask questions on Simpson's or Berkson's Paradox over 30 days ago?

Tags: discussion

I'm not referencing [Berkson's Paradox: How does pregnancy affect time for AIDS to emerge from women with HIV?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/320354/157457); did I ask other such questions now deleted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have asked three other questions with "Berkson's Paradox" in the title that are now deleted.  The most recent was two years ago.  All three were deleted by the [roomba / community user](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) as dead or abandoned.  The questions are:

- [Berkson's Paradox: Why wouldn't the wealthiest men in the conditioned set be nicer than the whole population's average person?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/320349/)
- [Berkson's Paradox: How does further conditioning increase the negative correlation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/320350/)
- [How is 'Conditioning on a collider' related to Berkson's Paradox?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/320360/)

Comment: Thanks. Can you please link to the ' three other questions with "Berkson's Paradox" in the title that are now deleted'?

Comment: I don't believe @gung or anybody else can do that. gung is a moderator, but what has been deleted is otherwise not accessible to you or anyone else not a moderator or SE staff.

Comment: @NickCox, it is possible to recover them, but I think we're not supposed to. I've searched, but I don't see a specific prohibition anywhere so I'll supply the links this time.

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal, see my comment to Nick above.  I've edited my answer to include the links.